# Error parsing an XSD schema - Undefined complexType

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, xsd, service-reference

I'm currently trying to add this XSD as a Service Reference to My ASP .Net MVC 4 project (http://voip.letscall.pt/PortalWebAPI/metadata?xsd=1). The problem is that whether I'm doing something wrong or the file has some kind of problem.
When I try to use the XSD.exe to parse the XSD, it gives me this error

> Undefined complexType
>   '[http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/VS.PortalWebAPI:SupportTypes:Paging](http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/VS.PortalWebAPI%3aSupportTypes%3aPaging)'
>   is used as a base for complex type extension.

The Paging SupportType is used on complexTypes, such as

```
<xs:complexType name="GetPbxCompanyContacts">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension xmlns:q13="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/VS.PortalWebAPI.API.SupportTypes" base="q13:Paging">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BranchId" type="xs:int" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Login" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="GetPbxCompanyContacts" nillable="true" type="tns:GetPbxCompanyContacts" />
```

The PortalWebAPI has 5 files:

XSDS

- Service Types (voip.letscall.pt/PortalWebAPI/metadata?xsd=1)
- Wcf Data Types (voip.letscall.pt/PortalWebAPI/metadata?xsd=0)
- Wcf Collection Types (voip.letscall.pt/PortalWebAPI/metadata?xsd=2)

WSDLS

- soap11 (voip.letscall.pt/PortalWebAPI/soap11)
- soap12 (voip.letscall.pt/PortalWebAPI/soap12)

However, I've still not managed to find how to use it. Do I need only one, or do I need to import all?

I've also tried to add it straight to the project, through References -> Add Service Reference, only one or all of them, but no luck.

Comment: Are you importing the schema that has `q13:Paging` defined? If so, please add more details to your question.

Comment: @helderdarocha I've updated the question with more info regarding the files. Neither of the XSDS have a definition for Paging.

Comment: *Neither of the XSD [schema document]s have a definition for Paging*.  Bingo.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a `complexType` named `Paging` in the XML schema document which has the target namespace mapped to the `q13` prefix. Look for the document with:

```
targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/VS.PortalWebAPI.API.SupportTypes"
```

It should contain the `Paging` type.

You also should have an `xs:import` statement:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/VS.PortalWebAPI.API.SupportTypes" 
           schemaLocation="/path/to/your-schema.xsd"/>
```

If the `Paging` type is not declared in that namespace, or if you don't import the schema, it will not be found when you try to use it in your extension.